Sporadic High CPU Usage in Laravel 11 with Increased Bootstrap Times
We are facing a perplexing issue with our Laravel 11 application and are looking for insights to resolve it.
Server Setup:

32-Core CPU
128GB RAM
SSD storage
Nginx
PHP-FPM: Limited to 20 processes

Traffic:

~4 million requests per day (evenly distributed)
~10% average server load

Issue:
Under normal conditions, the server performs optimally. However, sporadically, without any observable changes in traffic or external factors, the PHP-FPM processes spike to 100% CPU usage, causing the application to slow down significantly. This state persists for several hours before returning to normal without intervention.
Troubleshooting Steps:
We profiled the application using Tideways and identified that during the high-load periods, the primary difference is an increase in Laravel's bootstrap time (visible as the light blue bar in Tideways in the screenshot). Beyond this, we haven't found any clear triggers or anomalies in the environment.
Question:
Has anyone experienced similar issues or can provide guidance on what might cause these sporadic increases in bootstrap loading times?
Any suggestions or areas to investigate further would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you.

